# ulimit vs /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: security, pam, limit, ulimit

What is the difference between:

a) using the `ulimit` command to set a limit on a resource?

b) editing the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file for the same purpose?

e.g. what is the entry that should be placed in `/etc/security/limits.conf` to account for `ulimit -n 8192` ?

Is the limit set by `ulimit -n 8192` soft or hard?

For whom is it being set?

For the user running the command?

Or it becomes the default entry as if we were using `domain=*` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

Answer (score 4):

Changes made by `ulimit` will apply only to the current processes. If you need to make them permanent, you must edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`

About your 3rd question .. it depends what you run on your server, for certain applications you might need a higher number.

`ulimit -n` sets soft limit, `ulimit -Hn` sets hard limit.

Comment: Changes made by `ulimit` apply to the current _process_.

Comment: @JdeBP does this affect spawned processes too? they will inherit the `ulimit` set by their parent (or ancestor in general)?

Comment: Not if they have _already been forked_, which parts of the _current session_ may well have been.