# CentOS: ulimit hard/soft limits keep reset to default values

Tags: linux, centos, files, ulimit

On `CentOS7` I am trying to change the values of `ulimit` as following:

```
ulimit -Hn 262144
ulimit -Sn 100000
```

But due to some unknown trigger, the value is being reset to its default values:

```
[root@server001]# ulimit -Hn
4096
[root@server001]# ulimit -Sn
1024
```

Am I setting the values permanently this way? if not, how to do it?

And if it is permanent, why it is coming back to its default value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ulimit vs /etc/security/limits.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336855/ulimit-vs-etc-security-limits-conf)

Comment: It is. Thanks, you can mark it as an answer