# What is the scope of limits.conf?

Tags: linux, limit

The `limits.conf` (and related `limits.d`) are often cited as setting the default of `ulimit`s, which only affect the current process and its children. (See e.g. [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/61334), [U&L](https://(https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336855/ulimit-vs-etc-security-limits-conf))) Indeed, various docs for `limits.conf` and related components suggest that the limits are applied per-session:

> The pam_limits.so module **applies ulimit limits**, nice priority and number of simultaneous login sessions limit **to user login sessions**.
>
> From [Ubuntu `man limits.conf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/limits.conf.5.html)

However, various problems such as [process limits preventing login](https://serverfault.com/questions/412114/cannot-switch-ssh-to-specific-user-su-cannot-set-user-id-resource-temporaril) rely on `limits.conf` applying system-wide, per-user.

What exactly is the scope at which `limits.conf` and related limits apply?

Comment: The limits themselves are inherered from a parent process to child processes, so in that sense they are per-session. But AFAIK the process limit counts all processes of the user globally. Not processes in the same session or children of the same ancestor process or such.  The other limits are mostly about per-process amounts.